# How to bind Single View with Multiple Action in mvc5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi i am creating Dashboard for my application . It contain multiple action in controller. I want to bind Single View with multiple action, because i want to display different type of result in view. But Model in single model.That same model is used for every action.

**My Model (Customer Type ViewModel)**

```
public class CustomerTypeViewModel
{
    public System.Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string SalesCount { get; set; }
    public string CustomerType { get; set; }

    public List<View_VisitorsForm> Visits { get; set; }
}
}
```

**My Controller  (Here two actions there)**

Here i created two action and these two actions doing different calculations and model for these two actions is same(that is CustomerTypeViewModel) and also these two action is redirect to  same view.

```
   public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        List<Customer> n = (from c in db.Customers where c.IsDeleted == false select c).ToList();
        var customertype = string.Empty;
        List<CustomerTypeViewModel> obj = new List<CustomerTypeViewModel>();
        for (var i = 0; i < n.Count; i++)
        {
            var objCustomerName = n[i].DisplayName;
            var objCustomerID = n[i].CustomerID;
            var objCusCreatedDate = n[i].CreatedDate;
            var objNextDate = objCusCreatedDate.GetValueOrDefault().AddDays(120);
            var ObjTodayDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
            var salescount = (from sc in db.SalesOrders where sc.CustomerID == objCustomerID && sc.CreatedDate >= objCusCreatedDate && sc.CreatedDate <= objNextDate select sc.SalesOrderID).Count();
            var ordercount = (from oc in db.SalesOrders where oc.CustomerID == objCustomerID && oc.CreatedDate >= objCusCreatedDate && oc.CreatedDate <= ObjTodayDate select oc.SalesOrderID).Count();
            if (ordercount >= 3)
            {
                customertype = "Existing Customer";
            }
            else if (ordercount == 0 && ordercount <= 0)
            {
                customertype = "New Customer";
            }
            else if (ordercount <= 2 && ordercount >= 1)
            {
                customertype = "Potential Customer";
            }
            obj.Add(new CustomerTypeViewModel()
            {
                CustomerName = objCustomerName,
                CustomerType = customertype,
                SalesCount = ordercount.ToString()
            });
        }
        return View("Dashboard",obj);
    }
    public ActionResult NextFollowup()
    {
        var userID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString();
        var objEmpDepUTID = db.UserRightsSettings.Where(u => u.UserID.ToString() == userID).Select(e => new
        {
            objemployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
            objdepartmentID = e.DepartmentID,
            objusertypeID = e.UserTypeID
        }).FirstOrDefault();

        var EmployeeID = objEmpDepUTID.objemployeeID;
        var DepartmentID = objEmpDepUTID.objdepartmentID;
        var UserTypeID = objEmpDepUTID.objusertypeID;
        var TodayDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

        List<View_VisitorsForm> objVisitorsList = new List<View_VisitorsForm>();
        if (DepartmentID == new Guid("47D2C992-1CB6-44AA-91CA-6AA3C338447E") &&
           (UserTypeID == new Guid("106D02CC-7DC2-42BF-AC6F-D683ADDC1824") ||
           (UserTypeID == new Guid("B3728982-0016-4562-BF73-E9B8B99BD501"))))
        {
            objVisitorsList = db.View_VisitorsForm.Where(X => X.NextAppointment == TodayDate).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            objVisitorsList = db.View_VisitorsForm.Where(x => x.NextAppointment == TodayDate && x.EmployeeID == EmployeeID).ToList();
        }
        CustomerTypeViewModel objvvm = new CustomerTypeViewModel();
        objvvm.Visits = objVisitorsList;
        return View("Dashboard",objvvm);
    }
```

**My View**

In this view i gave model as like this means it shows error

```
   @model CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models.CustomerTypeViewModel
   @using CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models
```

It shows error near to

```
 @Model.Select(x => x.CustomerName).Count()
```

if i give model name with IEnumerable like

```
   @model IEnumerable<CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models.CustomerTypeViewModel>
   @using CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models
```

it shows error near to  table (Model.Visits)that is

```
         @foreach (View_VisitorsForm item in Model.Visits)
```

**My Full View**

```
@model CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models.CustomerTypeViewModel
@using CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="container body">
<div class="main_container">
  <div class="right_col" role="main">
        <!-- top tiles -->
   <div class="row tile_count">

   <div class="right">
   <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total Customer</span>
   <div class="count">@Model.Select(x => x.CustomerName).Count()</div>
   </div>

  <div class="right">
  <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Existing Customer</span>
  <div class="count">@Model.Where(x => x.CustomerType == "Existing Customer").Count()</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
  <table>
  <thead>
         <tr>
                <th>Employee </th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>Purpose of Visit</th>
         </tr>
  <thead>
 <tbody>
          @foreach (View_VisitorsForm item in Model.Visits)
          {
          <tr>
               <td>@item.Employee;</td>
               <td>@item.CustomerName;</td>
               <td>@item.POVisit;</td>
          </tr>
          }
 <tbody>
 </table>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

My Question is little long .I tried my level best to explain this issue. Any one understand my question and help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks..

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve? `@Model.Select(x => x.CustomerName).Count()` makes no sense, CustomerName is a string, you can't count it. And if you make your view's model a list, you can't loop through the visitors without selecting which of the model items you want to take the visitors from (i.e. Model.Visits no longer exists because Model is a list, you'd need a foreach loop over the items in Model)

Comment: Also, making the view's model a list makes no sense because both your actions are only returning a single object to it, not a list

Comment: @ADyson See this image . Before i created separate controller and Separate view and as per  that count i bring the output  [![Count][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNNIq.jpg

Comment: sorry I don't understand how that is relevant? Are you showing me output from the same view as in your code sample? And what is `[![Count][1]][1] [1]` - I don't recognise that syntax?

Comment: your view is showing details about one customer. If you want something which shows a count of lots of customers then I think you need a separate database query to count them, and to put the result as an item of data in the ViewBag which you can use in the page, separate to the model. Or, if this data is going to be a header across lots of screens, implement it as a partial view which you can then use in many pages.

Comment: @ADyson That is image here i cant able to paste the image  i can able to provide the link of image . That is only [![Count][1]][1] [1] image name that is not syntax

Comment: @ADyson See my first action in that i calculated the whole Customer count which is in the Customer name and in that count i found who is new Customer Existing Customer and Potential Customer

Comment: @ADyson    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jquq.jpg See this image and my first action I calculated the total no of Customer which is in  the customer table first . Then in that i calculated the New , existing, potential Customer based on Sales order that calulation also in that action In the image i showed the count of Customer (in blue colour Total Customer, New Customer, Potential Customer,) . Same like that i showed in my Dashboard

Comment: ok so I was mistaken before. Your two actions are returning different models to the view - the first one returns a list, the second one returns a single item. That's impossible. A view can only have one model. Hence you get errors when you return the wrong type of object to the view.

Comment: @ADyson Why we cant use multiple model in single view?

Comment: it's a limitation of ASP.NET MVC. You declare @model at the top of the View and it's a fixed property. It's a perfectly logical limitation, IMO. If you don't declare what the model is, then how would the View know how to interpret the model data you send it? It wouldn't know what the possible fields were, or the data types of those fields, or the structure of the object.

Comment: If you want to send a different model back, you need another view. It's not logical to expect the same view to deal with a completely different type of information. Even if the difference is simply that one model is `List<T>` and one model is `T` it's sufficient to make the definition of @model different and therefore the View won't know what to do when you make a statement like @Model.MyProperty - if you send it a different set of data with different structure, then MyProperty may not exist, and the View can't deal with that.

Comment: adyson In top i mention the model name @model CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models.CustomerTypeViewModel This is the model and i used same model for two actions

Comment: no, you didn't. the first action returns List<CustomerTypeViewModel> and the second action returns CustomerTypeViewModel. As I've just explained, they are different models. Only the second one is compatible with your View

Comment: See my second action adyson in second action also i return list only see above of  if condition in Second action

Comment: No. Your code reads `CustomerTypeViewModel objvvm = new CustomerTypeViewModel(); ... return View("Dashboard",objvvm);`. `objvvm` is a single instance of CustomerTypeViewModel, not a list.

Comment: In Second action i trying to show the table See my viiew code in View code i gave Model .Visits in for each statement . In Second action i assign that objVisitorslist to Visits

Comment: yes, but visits is just a sub-property of CustomerTypeViewModel, it's not your main model.

Comment: ADyson  see this  image   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnXkm.jpg                       Yes objvm is single instance i assign that OBJVisitorsList to Visits which is in CustomerType View model                                                                                CustomerTypeViewModel objvvm = new CustomerTypeViewModel();
            objvvm.Visits = objVisitorsList;
            return View(objvvm);     I created Separate view for my second action and i got the table output i will show that in my above image

Comment: ok great. So now only the first action is a problem?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyUXF.jpg See this image i create separate view for my second action and output is in second image .

Comment: Yes Adyson the first action only problem. I want to show the count

Comment: I want to show the Count which i calculated in the First action which i mentioned in the first image and below of that i want to show the table as per second action

Comment: but the visits only apply to one Customer Type, right? So if you have 4 customer types, you will need 4 visit tables, right? Because visits is a property of the customer type.

Comment: Wait i Will explain you clearly

Comment: I have one table called customer in that table i have many value. In that table i want to show the total count of values Eg i have 400 values in that table so i gave that 400 values as Total Customer. then i wrote one condition in my First action                                                                                         var ordercount = (from oc in db.SalesOrders where oc.CustomerID == objCustomerID && oc.CreatedDate >= objCusCreatedDate && oc.CreatedDate <= ObjTodayDate select oc.SalesOrderID).Count();                  Here i take the sales count .

Comment: Depend upon that sales count i separate the Customer count values as New Existing potential and assign that value to CustomerType

Comment: yes I see that. Although your view is never using these values!

Comment: also you metioned "i want the table as per section action". So I assumed you wanted the "Visits" table. But since Visits is associated to a specific CustomerType (as per the design of your CustomerTypeViewModel class), you would need to loop through all the customer type objects returned by the first action and show a visits table for each one. And for this you'd (firstly) need to change the model of the View to match what is returned by the first action. `@model IEnumerable<CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models.CustomerTypeViewModel> `

Comment: Then you would need a `@foreach (item in Model)` loop. `item` will then be a single instance of `CustomerTypeViewModel`. So you can loop through them and display the counts and the visits.

Comment: Wait I will show you how  i want

Comment: [![Dashboard][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DomTM.jpg See this image Depend upon first action i brough that Total Customer New Customer Potential Customer   . and the model name is CustomerType ViewModel now below i created one table. In that i can't able to bring table depend upon second action (which is marked in red colour) and model of second action is CustomerType Viewmodel. Model is same for both action

Comment: I see. So you do want it all on one page. In which case 2 actions is no good, because you can't run them both _simultaneously_ into the same view (even if they returned the same model type). And it looks like the Visits list is not dependent on the customer type, which means that making it a sub-property of CustomerTypeViewModel, as you have done, is not meaningful or logical. Give me some time I will write an answer which I think will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, and the screenshot provided (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DomTM.jpg) I think I now understand what it is you want to achieve.

The problem is that your approach has a number of logical flaws.

1) Your View has its model defined as `CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models.CustomerTypeViewMo‌​del`, but your `Dashboard` action is trying to provide a `IEnumerable<CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models.CustomerTypeViewMo‌​del>` as the model. These two are incompatible types.

2) In the question, you asked about whether you can use multiple actions with a single View. The answer to that is yes (providing they both supply the correct model type). However, you can't call two Actions on the same View *at the same time* (i.e. during the same request). Based on your requirements, it appears you want the data returned by both the `Dashboard` and `NextFollowUp` Action methods to be visible in the single View, all at once. This isn't possible by using two action methods. You'd only use multiple action methods if you wanted the View to have different contents at different times.

3) In the `CustomerTypeViewMo‌​del` class, you've defined `List<View_VisitorsForm> Visits` as a property of the class. This implies that the list of Vists is somehow connected to a specific `CustomerType`, i.e. the vists contained in that list in any one instance of `CustomerTypeViewMo‌​del` would be ones relating only to the CustomerType being represented by that instance. It's now clear from the requirements that this is not the case. Instead the data contains in the visits list is not determined by Customer Type, it's determined by who the current system user is. Therefore making this list a property of `CustomerType` is an illogical association which caused some confusion.

4) In the view code, because @model is wrongly defined as a single instance of `CustomerTypeViewMo‌​del` instead of `IEnumerable<CustomerTypeViewMo‌​del>` . Despite this, you tried to somehow count the number of objects in the list by using `@Model.Select(x => x.CustomerName).Count()`. This doesn't work because the View doesn't think `@Model` is a `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can't do a `Select` on it.

5) The `CustomerTypeViewModel` class also seems to be more of a representation of a Customer than a Customer Type - it contains fields such as customer name, and sales count which aren't even needed for this View. So this is another logical problem. If the ViewModel is called `CustomerType` then it should entirely represent a Customer Type, not a Customer, and should not contain unrelated fields.

Given all of that, your design needs a complete rethink. You need a higher-level ViewModel object which will include both the list of CustomerTypes and also the list of Visits. This can then be returned to the view, and you can

a) loop through the list of CustomerTypes to display all the statistics

b) loop through the list of Visits to display all the visitors.

Therefore the `Dashboard` action will build this `DashboardViewModel` object and return it to the View. The `NextFollowUp` action is no longer necessary and can be removed.

The code should look something like the following. I haven't tested it so apologies if there are any syntax errors or similar.

**View Model**

```
//This no longer includes Visits, because they aren't specific to a CustomerType
public class CustomerType
{
  public string CustomerTypeDescription { get; set; }
  public int CustomerCount { get; set; }
}

//This is now the ViewModel used by the View:
public class DashboardViewModel
{
   public List<CustomerType> CustomerTypes { get; set; }
   public List<View_VisitorsForm> Visits { get; set; }
}
```

**Action method**

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    //first work out the customer type statistics
    List<Customer> customers = (from c in db.Customers where c.IsDeleted == false select c).ToList();

    CustomerType allCustomers = new CustomerType();
    allCustomers.CustomerTypeDescription = "Total Customers";
    allCustomers.CustomerCount = customers.Count;

    CustomerType existingCustomers = new CustomerType();
    existingCustomers.CustomerTypeDescription = "Existing Customers";

    CustomerType potentialCustomers = new CustomerType();
    potentialCustomers.CustomerTypeDescription = "Potential Customers";

    CustomerType newCustomers = new CustomerType();
    newCustomers.CustomerTypeDescription = "New Customers";


    foreach (Customer cus in customers)
    {
        var ordercount = (from oc in db.SalesOrders where oc.CustomerID == cus.CustomerID && oc.CreatedDate >= cus.CreatedDate && oc.CreatedDate <= DateTime.Now.Date select oc.SalesOrderID).Count();

        if (ordercount >= 3)
        {
          existingCustomers.CustomerCount++;
        }
        else if (ordercount == 2 || ordercount == 1)
        {
          potentialCustomers.CustomerCount++;
        }
        else if (ordercount <= 0)
        {
          newCustomers.CustomerCount++;
        }
    }

    //now get the list of visits
    var userID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString();
    var currentUser = db.UserRightsSettings.Where(u => u.UserID.ToString() == userID).Select(e => new
    {
        employeeID = e.EmployeeID,
        departmentID = e.DepartmentID,
        usertypeID = e.UserTypeID
    }).FirstOrDefault();

    List<View_VisitorsForm> visitList = new List<View_VisitorsForm>();
    if (currentUser.departmentID == new Guid("47D2C992-1CB6-44AA-91CA-6AA3C338447E") &&
       (currentUser.usertypeID == new Guid("106D02CC-7DC2-42BF-AC6F-D683ADDC1824") ||
       (currentUser.usertypeID == new Guid("B3728982-0016-4562-BF73-E9B8B99BD501")))
    {
        visitList = db.View_VisitorsForm.Where(X => X.NextAppointment == DateTime.Now.Date).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        visitList = db.View_VisitorsForm.Where(x => x.NextAppointment == DateTime.Now.Date && x.EmployeeID == currentUser.employeeID).ToList();
    }

    //finally bring it all together to create the ViewModel
    DashboardViewModel vm = new DashboardViewModel();
    vm.CustomerTypes = new List<CustomerType>();
    vm.CustomerTypes.Add(allCustomers);
    vm.CustomerTypes.Add(existingCustomers);
    vm.CustomerTypes.Add(potentialCustomers);
    vm.CustomerTypes.Add(newCustomers);
    vm.Visits = visitList;

    return View("Dashboard", vm);
}
```

**View**

```
@model CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models.DashboardViewModel
@using CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container body">
  <div class="main_container">
    <div class="right_col" role="main">
      <!-- top tiles -->
      <div class="row tile_count">
      @foreach (CustomerType cusType in Model.CustomerTypes)
      {
        <div class="right">
         <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>@cusType.CustomerTypeDescription</span>
         <div class="count">@cusType.CustomerCount</div>
        </div>
      }
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Employee </th>
              <th>Customer Name</th>
              <th>Purpose of Visit</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          @foreach (View_VisitorsForm visit in Model.Visits)
          {
            <tr>
              <td>@visit.Employee;</td>
              <td>@visit.CustomerName;</td>
              <td>@visit.POVisit;</td>
            </tr>
          }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this is of some use to you and helps to clarify your thinking. In future, if you design your ViewModel carefully in advance and think about the possible data that's required, and make sure that any classes you create actually represent the logical entity they are named after, and don't contain items not related to that entity, then it will be a lot easier to understand your own code and make things work smoothly.

Some other brief comments on your code:

- you had some redundant variables in there (in particular var salescount). Don't leave code lying around which isn't being used - it confuses things.
- there was some incorrect html (e.g. you had `<thead>` twice: `<thead>...``instead of closing the tag properly:`...`.
- The code was more verbose that it needed to be. For example, all the declarations of EmployeeID, DepartmentID, which were then only used once more. They were a direct mapping from an earlier variable, so just use that instead.
- use meaningful variable names which can be understood throughout the code without referring back to the definition (e.g. use `List<Customer> customers` for a list of customers instead of `List<Customer> n`, and don't call anything simple `obj` - there's no chance of knowing what it is.
- C# is a strongly-typed language, therefore you don't really need to use [Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) to prefix variable names (i.e. `objEmpDepUTID`, `objVisitorsList`). In any case you also used the `obj` prefix incorrectly in many places, when the variable's type was actually a primitive like a string or int, and not an object at all. Opinions on the use of this vary, but generally I find it just clutters up the code and doesn't convey any information that can't already been seen by reading the rest of the code (or using the Intellisense in Visual Studio).

N.B. It appears from the screenshot that there are also some other contents of the View (Device Usage, Quick Settings etc) but you haven't provided details of these so I'm going to assume you will add these to the ViewModel later.

Comment: Adyson i am getting Error . I tried your code first i tried ur first action that is order count itself in view i am getting object reference is null error near to @forEach(cus in CustmoerType)

Comment: without being able to test it's difficult for me to say exactly, but I've made a small edit, adding the line `vm.CustomerTypes = new List<CustomerType>();` into the Action method near the end, just in case the list is not being initialised properly. See if that helps.

Comment: Yes it shows error near to Dashboardviewmodel. Now i altered as per you said and have a check and let you know

Comment: I've also added strong typing to two of the loops, which I'd missed:    `@foreach (CustomerType cusType in Model.CustomerTypes)
` (in the view) and `foreach (Customer cus in customers)` in the action - sometimes the compiler might complain about this

Comment: Adyson the first action is is working  I have to check with second one

Comment: both action are working but it is dashboard i want to show some more result in the same dashboard  so my doubt is if i add the some more calculation in the same action means it wont be like code complexity

Comment: ok well if it's working and my answer has helped you please mark the answer as accepted and/or give an upvote - thanks :-)

Comment: I agree if you start adding more things to the action method it might start to get complex, but then it's a complex page. You could split it up into smaller private methods to break it up, or devolve some functionality to other classes - it depends how you want to design it and whether you'd like to be able to re-use the same functionality somewhere else (e.g. if you showed the customer count on several pages you could move the code that calculates that into a separate class which could be used in multiple action methods. It's really down to what your other requirments are.

Comment: cant able to create multiple action using your method ??

Comment: why exactly do you want multiple actions? You only need multiple actions if you want either (a) multiple different views, or (b) the same view but with the data provided to be different (e.g. list calculated with different parameters or something), or (c) differentiation between GET and POST methods. The screenshot you showed and requirements you gave are not covered by any of these situations.

Comment: I need same view different results now i showed  2 results based on list next in the same view i want to use get and post method

Comment: you would only really use POST if you have got a HTML form (maybe in a different view) and you want to submit the parameters entered by the user and then show the original view based on those parameters. Is that your situation?

Comment: Actually next i am going to keep two date text boxes  and one button   if i select date and click button means it have to come controller and based on that dates it have to show the count of data . This i have to keep under 2 second action result

Comment: ok sure. So you can make another action which will receive this parameters using POST method. If you then want to use the same code to populate your page, I suggest you make another class (or a private method within the controller would be adequate) containing the all the logic currently in the `Dashboard` action, which constructs the `DashboardViewModel` object. Move that logic into your separate class/method and have it return an instance of `DashboardViewModel`, and then you can call it from both action methods.

Comment: ... You can pass some optional parameters into that method as well (e.g. your dates) and change the logic a little so that it will use these dates to filter the data, if they are present. This pattern of design is just applying the simple principles of code re-use (or the DRY principle - "Don't Repeat Yourself") which you should try to follow in every line of code you write :-)

Comment: that means u ask me to create one new private action in controller and ask me to write the logic of that date parameter. But i got one doubt in that  i have to write entire logic which we wrote in dashboard in separate private action or just that date logic in private action

Comment: Well, like everything, it depends on your requirements. If you need all that functionality to depend on date parameters, and be available to another action then put all of it in there. If not, just move the parts that need to be shared across different actions, and have it return a DashboardViewModel that's only partially populated, and the calling action can finish populating the rest as required for that specific action. It's your decision.

Comment: Also just a terminology note which might be helpful: say "private method" for this situation, not "private action". An action is shorthand for a method that returns an ActionResult to a View. Therefore logically an "action" can't be private, because then a View couldn't see it or run it. So what you want to create is a private method, which returns some data object(s), not a view. Probably you call this method from an "action" method.